# Difference in behavior with convert 108 and format while using Datediff

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I am trying to extract HH:MM:SS part from a datetime field and using it to get the date difference in minutes between the extracted parts. However I am getting different behavior with conver (108) which is giving me accurate results and format is giving incorrect results.

```
declare @DATE1 SMALLDATETIME = '2019-02-22 06:15:00' 
, @DATE2 SMALLDATETIME = '2019-02-22 14:15:00' 

 select datediff( minute, convert(varchar(10), @DATE1,108) 
,convert(varchar(10), @DATE2,108) ) [Total Mins from Convert], 
convert(varchar(10), @DATE1,108) [Value from Convert] ,  
format(@DATE1,'hh:mm:ss') [Value from Format]  ,
 datediff( minute,  cast(format(@DATE1,'hh:mm:ss') as time) , 
cast(format(@DATE2,'hh:mm:ss') as time) ) [Total Mins from Format]
```

Output:

```
  Total Mins from Convert   Value from Convert  Value from Format   Total Mins from Format
480                             06:15:00        06:15:00                  -240
```

I can use convert without any issues to get date difference correctly but wanted to understand why Format is showing differences when the HH:MM:SS is same with convert. If am giving @date2 variable <= 12 pm it is giving me correct results with both 'Format' and 'Convert', how ever if my @hour is more than 12 pm like 14:15 in this example it is giving me incorrect results.

is it because format has 12 hour time format while convert has 24 hour time format ? is it possible to change the time format for 'Format' Function. Can any one help me with explanation and changing the behavior with Format function if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `HH` to represent 24 hour time:

```
SELECT
    DATEDIFF(minute, CONVERT(varchar(10), @DATE1, 108),
        CONVERT(varchar(10), @DATE2, 108)) [Total Mins from Convert], 
    CONVERT(varchar(10), @DATE1, 108) [Value from Convert],
    FORMAT(@DATE1,'HH:mm:ss') [Value from Format],
    DATEDIFF(minute, CAST(FORMAT(@DATE1,'hh:mm:ss') AS time),
        CAST(FORMAT(@DATE2, 'HH:mm:ss') AS time)) [Total Mins from Format];
```

This outputs `480` for both minutes values, and `06:15:00` for both times.

Comment: Thank You @Tim for your help for providing information,  yeah that was the difference.  Currently it does not allow me to accept the answer, I will accept later.

Answer (score 0):

I think hh and HH implies different results, hh is 12 hour format it looks like, and HH is 24 hour format.

explained clearly here:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2655/format-sql-server-dates-with-format-function/

```
select datediff( minute, convert(varchar(10), @DATE1,108) ,convert(varchar(10), @DATE2,108) ) [Total Mins from Convert], 
convert(varchar(10), @DATE1,108) [Value from Convert] ,  
format(@DATE1,'HH:mm:ss') [Value from Format]  ,
 datediff( minute,  cast(format(@DATE1,'HH:mm:ss') as time) , cast(format(@DATE2,'HH:mm:ss') as time) ) [Total Mins from Format]
```

Now the results look like this:

```
Total Mins from Convert   Value from Convert  Value from Format   Total Mins from Format
480                             06:15:00        06:15:00                  -240
```

Answer (score 0):

I realise you have already accepted an answer, but if I were to calculate the difference in minutes, I find it is far easier to convert them to floats and do some simple arithmetic.

Answer added here for completeness.

```
declare @DATE1 SMALLDATETIME = '2019-02-22 06:15:00' 
, @DATE2 SMALLDATETIME = '2019-02-22 14:15:00' 

select convert(float,@date2-@date1)*24*60 as DiffInMinutes
```

Result:

```
DiffInMinutes
480
```